# jQuery - Create cookie for current toggleClass state?

Tags: jquery, cookies, toggle

I want to create a cookie for the current state if this toggle...

My code:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'esc', function() {
   $("nav").toggleClass('blue');
   return false;
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

set cookie:

```
$.cookie("cookie_name", "state");
```

read cookie:

```
var value = $.cookie("cookie_name");
```

Comment: you need to specify that this is not built-in functionality, it requires a plug-in

Answer (score 0):

Try this (together with a jQuery cookie plug-in like http://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

```
// get previous state and initiate the class
if($.cookie("state") == 1) {
    $('nav').addClass("blue");
} else {
    $('nav').removeClass("blue");
}

$(document).bind('keydown', 'esc', function() {
    $("nav").toggleClass('blue');
    if($("nav").hasClass("blue")) {
        $.cookie("state", 1);
    } else {
        $.cookie("state", 0);
    }
    return false;
});
```